# resize groupbox with sleep between iteration show up after loop ends

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, sleep, groupbox

I make new project and simplified it to check if this bug is real, and this is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            groupBox1.Height += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Height += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Put on form 2 buttons, groupBox and textBox, and watch how textBox smoothly change between iterations, and groupBox **change after** loop ends. Why this is happening?

I tested it on .NET 2.0 and 3.5 - same effect.

Comment: What makes this especially odd is that Panel does not exhibit the same behavior as GroupBox, although Panel is a ScrollableControl whereas GroupBox is just a Control... As a side note, adding groupBox1.Refresh() in the loop forces the groupbox to grow smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - +1 - as i have solution i can program further and just wait for answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the underlying reason why the GroupBox behaves differently from TextBox or Panel, but it might have to do with the fact that GroupBox is used as a container control but doesn't actually inherit from any container types. Panel inherits from ScrollableControl, which might add some additional layout logic.

If the concern is just getting it to grow smoothly, you can add `groupBox1.Refresh();` to your code to accomplish this.